# Chrome tabCapture captureCannot read properties of undefined (reading 'capture')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture the audio from the active tab but it always doesn't let me access it.
chrome.tabCapture.capture

manifest.json

```
"name": "hola mundo",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "translate ",
"manifest_version": 3,
"author": "yo",
"action":{
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "translate index"
},
"host_permissions": [
    "https://*/"
],
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "tabCapture",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads",
    "storage",
   "scripting"
]
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(request)
    startCapture()
  });
  const startCapture = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
      console.log("tabs",tabs)
      idTab = tabs[0].id
      chrome.storage.sync.get({
        maxTime: 1200000,
        muteTab: false,
        format: "mp3",
        quality: 192,
        limitRemoved: false
      }, (options) => {
        let time = options.maxTime;
        if(time > 1200000) {
          time = 1200000
        }
        chrome.tabCapture.capture(
          {
            audio: true
          },
          (stream) => {
              console.log(stream)
          }
        )
      });
   
    });
  };
```

console log
shows the active tab but from the background you can't access the capture

page url options.html

```
chrome-extension://cnmcidbjhkbfbgngfefepkldjplnogpa/options.html
tabs [{…}]0: {active: true, audible: false, autoDiscardable: true, discarded: false, groupId: -1, …}length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'capture')
```

Comment: You can't use it in ManifestV3 background script, https://crbug.com/1214847. Use it in a separate window or in the popup.

Comment: ok perfect by feedback

Comment: I just added it to a separate page and the same error appears, chrome-extension://cnmcidbjhkbfbgngfefepkldjplnogpa/options.html @wOxxOm

Comment: Try reinstalling the extension. Also make sure you open the options page using the browser's UI so that the page indeed has a chrome-extension:// URL, not a file:// or localhost. If nothing helps it may be a bug in ManifestV3.

Comment: hi, that's what did chrome-extension://cnmcidbjhkbfbgngfefepkldjplnogpa/options.html @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

it is a known bug in manifest_version 3.
v2 works fine.